# Lodash and underscore.string into AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, lodash, underscore.string.js

The question is simple, how to successfully implement [`Lodash`](https://lodash.com/) with [`underscore.string`](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) library into AngularJS project?

It is necessary to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo can use **angular-underscore**

please see here https://github.com/floydsoft/angular-underscore

or **angular-lodash**

https://github.com/cabrel/angular-lodash

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sylwester reply I figured it out, but his answer was just a hint, so I decided to enrich it a bit more.

#### It is necessary to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to achieve this?

No, you don't need to use RequireJS to implement both libraries together into AngularJS project. But it can be easily achieved - just look at this [article](http://blog.falafel.com/the-lo-dash-on-underscorejs-and-strings/).

### Implementation without RequireJS

1. Use [angular-lodash](https://github.com/cabrel/angular-lodash) or [angular-underscore](https://github.com/floydsoft/angular-underscore) (depends what's your implementation)
2. Then download [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) to your project:

   ```
   $ bower install underscore.string --save-dev
   ```
3. Finally make sure that libraries were added to your `index.html`:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/loadash/lodash.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-loadash/angular-loadash.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/underscore.string/underscore.string.js">
   ```

Feel free to improve this answer with RequireJS.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to actually call a function from underscore.string, after the js files are loaded as you wrote above ?

Comment: Take a look on [this article](http://blog.falafel.com/the-lo-dash-on-underscorejs-and-strings/). I've mentioned about it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

create this service and now you can use underscore.string in underscore.js

something like: _.capitalize('hello') --> 'Hello'

```
angular.module('underscore', []).factory('_', ['$window', function($window) {
    $window._.mixin(s.exports());
    return $window._;
}]);
```